# how to model device/user in amazon dynamo db

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

How to model device/user in amazon dynamo db with the following model

```
class device {

set <user> users;

}

class user {

string id;
string distance;
}
```

later, i would like to find out which is closet user given device zip code and radius.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: should this need custom marshallers like https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1K7U34AOZBLJ2/Using-Custom-Marshallers-to-Store-Complex-Objects-in-Amazon-DynamoDB. If yes, should the custom marshaller need to create the set ?

Comment: The data model is less important.. please explain what are you trying to build. What is a primary key and what are the fast queries you will need.